# call a vb script from SSRS 2008

Tags: vbscript, export, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel

Is it possible to call a VB script from SSRS 2008?

What I am trying to do is:

1. Generate an automated report in SSRS 2008
2. Export this report to a designated location in CSV format.
3. Call a VB script that converts this CSV generated file to .xlsx file

How can I do this?

Comment: is the problem that you cannot export to xlsx from SSRS 2008?  (and xls file is not sufficient?).   Otherwise, you can simply create a subscription and output the xls file to a file location.